# What is the difference between ToString and GetDisplayText Methods C#

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I'm working on an assignment with an abstract base class, 3 child classes, one of which is also abstract that has 2 grandchild classes.

I'm thinking the `GetDisplayText()` method replicates what the parent class has, then I only need to add the additional parameters (signature) of the child class.

If I use the `ToString()` method, I'll have to code all the formatting again with the additional parameters (signature) of the child.

And yes, I do understand that the abstract classes use virtual as in:

```
public virtual string ToString() {}

public virtual string GetDisplayText() {}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What's your base class? There's no GetDisplayText on the standard base objects IIRC

Comment: You need to advice to override ToString() or create new virtual method as GetDisplaText()?

Comment: I'm asking which is the better method to use with multiple inheritances.  I'm sorry, my question turned into "thinking out-loud" so to speak.

Comment: @user1754874 The one that does what your application needs. If they both do, flip a coin.

Answer (score 3):

In types that don't directly represent a value (like GUI elements, which is what MSDN tells me has a `GetDisplayText()` method), it's more common to use `ToString()` to provide a representation of the object suitable for debugging, not display purposes. (I.e. a textual dump of important properties of the object.) So I'm (wildly) guessing they added `GetDisplayText()` to components that should have a plaintext UI representation (say, an item in a dropdown list) to let you distinguish between the concerns "what do I present in the UI?" and "what's the internal state of this object?"

Comment: My UI is just a list box.  The data is stored in an XML file.

Comment: @user1754874 So? How is that relevant to your question?

Comment: I'm in community college, the text book is Murach's C# 2010, the examples in the book are using GetDisplayText() the instructor's examples use ToString().  I don't know what the difference is between these two methods.

Comment: @user1754874 They might be interchangeable for whichever purpose they're being used in those examples. (It would've helped to include those in your question to provide some context.) Have you asked your instructor?

Comment: My instructor is very intelligent and has a difficult time answering simple questions.  And so it seems I have a difficult time asking simple questions.  I did research this question to no avail before asking here.